# Javascript only partially running after loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript that was working up until recently on this page:

https://www.sosc.org/findaprogram

What is supposed to happen is you type in the Zip code  and it takes you to a certain page based on what you type. It works with the first 200 instances of the code, but the remainder are erroring out.

An example is if you type 91011 it takes you to this page: [www.sosc.org/central](http://www.sosc.org/central). However if you type in 90016, it should take you to the same page, but it errors out. The only reason I can find is that it is lower in the js document

Here are the JS files I am linking to:

```
<script src="file/js/zipscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="file/js/zipcodes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And they are located here:
https://www.sosc.org/file/js/zipscript.js
and
https://www.sosc.org/file/js/zipcodes.js

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is the `programURL` function in zipscript.js. You definitely don't want to call `document.location = '/error';` for every single one of over 1000 mismatches. You want to do this exactly once, and only in case the for loop has finished without finding a single match. Also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Here's fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/sdc4qt7z/

Comment: Thank you for the tips.

Tried it an console is giving me the warning

"Uncaught ReferenceError: zipform is not defined"

Here is the page I am testing it on:
<http://www.sosc.org/findaprogramtest>

Comment: That part refers to `<form id="zipform">`; you need to use your form's ID instead.

Comment: My form ID is "zipform". Still getting the same console prompt?

Comment: In that case the script is included above the form, and when the script runs, the form doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I put the script it below the form ID code and still getting the same console error:
<http://www.sosc.org/findaprogramtest>

Comment: Your HTML is malformed; you've put my example form *inside* your own form. This makes the browser ignore the inner <form> tag, which is why the code doesn't find the element. My code isn't supposed to be used as-is anyway; you'd have to put all zip codes and locations into the `pages` variable first.